# Blender smooths fbx model at import

Tags: import, .fbx, smooth

I need to display a 3D model on Sketchfab. This 3D model is generated from Autodesk which exports a FBX file.

If I import this fbx file directly in Sketchfab, the rendering corresponds to what is in Autodesk.

But not if I import it into Blender, the rendering is all rounded. If I create a fbx or blend file from Blender and import it into Sketchfab, the rendering is also rounded.

I tried to modify the import parameters in Blender without result.

How to avoid this ?

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to click on the *Properties Window > Object > Shade Auto Smooth*.